# Impact of reboiling wort

Tags: hops, boil

Long story short, *somehow* after a chilling my beer after the boil, I've ended up with additional water in the wort (must have a leak in the chiller!).

Took me a while to notice, couldn't understand why my OG was 20points off!

As a result I need to boil the wort for another hour to get down to my intended volume.

What effect will this have on the beer? I guess I'll lose all of those hop aromas from late additions in the first boil?

For reference it's an APA with hop additions at 60, 15 & 0min.

I intend to do another hop stand to make up for this, but fully expecting the 2nd boil to have a detrimental effect on the beer...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to clarify. You're reboiling wort at this point not beer. Boiling beer is a different issue.

In your case the effects will be that your late hop additions will now add to IBU and lose most the aroma and flavor a late addition adds.

Comment: Right you are! Edited for clarity. Will the previous hop additions add to the IBU if they've been removed from the wort? I had them in a hop spider & removed after the first boil.

Comment: Yes. But not to thier full potential. I've not seen IBU conversion studies on suspended lupulin, but it most definitely does. If I had to guess about 5% of the lupulin gets suspended every minute in hot water (130°F+)